Where are the Portal 2 Puzzle Maker sound effects located?
Where are the sound effects for the Portal 2 Puzzle Maker located? I looked through pak01_dir.vpk but I couldn't find them anywhere.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
